# Why I can use sort_by_key with a Vec?

Tags: rust

Taking this example

```
fn main() {

    let mut test: Vec<u32> = Vec::new(); 

    test.push(5);
    test.push(8);
    test.push(0);

    test.sort_by_key(|k| k.abs());
}
```

I searched [the source code for `Vec`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c66d2380a810c9a2b3dbb4f93a830b101ee49cc2/src/libcollections/vec.rs), but I do not see a trait or something like `derive`.

```
trait SomeTrait {
    fn sort_by_key...
}

impl SomeTrait for Vec... { }
```

The IntelliSense of my IDE did not detect `sort_by_key` either.

I searched the Rust Github and found [this implementation in slice.rs](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c66d2380a810c9a2b3dbb4f93a830b101ee49cc2/src/libcollections/slice.rs#L784):

```
pub fn sort_by_key<B, F>(&mut self, mut f: F)
    where F: FnMut(&T) -> B, B: Ord
{
    self.sort_by(|a, b| f(a).cmp(&f(b)))
}
```

But I can not see how `Vec` relates to a slice and how `Vec` can access `sort_by_key`.

I saw this constructor in `vec.rs`:

```
pub fn new() -> Vec<T> {
    Vec {
        buf: RawVec::new(),
        len: 0,
    }
}
```

I navigated the `struct` but I fail to understand where `sort_by_key` comes from.

---

After the [response by Jascha](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437375/vec-that-way-you-can-use-sort-by-key-what-is-the-relationship#36437902)

I can not understand the documentation as my English is not very good. I  understand that by using `Deref`, the struct that implements `Deref` can access methods to which it applies, in this case a slice, but it could be another?

---

I found [this url](http://ncameron.org/nool15.pdf) which helps me understand my follow up question and may help others:

```
struct Foo;
impl Foo {
     fn foo(&self) { }
}

struct Bar {
    foo: Foo,
}

impl std::ops::Deref for Bar {
     type Target = Foo;

    fn deref(&self) -> &Foo {
        &self.foo
    }
}

fn main() {
    let test: Bar = Bar { foo: Foo }; 
    test.foo();  
}
```

*I think this is very cool*

Comment: I cannot understand this question at all -- can you maybe rewrite some components of it?

Comment: @ￜＺＶￜ I update I hope you understand better. Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`Vec<T>` implements `Deref<Target=[T]>` (`[T]` is a slice). You can find more about deref coercions [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html). The API documentation even lists all [methods](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.sort_by_key) accessible through `Deref`.

Comment: I was at this -> https://doc.rust-lang.org/collections/vec/struct.Vec.html the link you put is more detailed thanks. I and looking rust/vec.rs see now deref and I look more about it Thank for your time.

Comment: You can help me with this, I can not really understand the documentation (my English is not very good), I can understand that using Deref, the struct that implements Deref can access methods to which it applies, in this case is slice, but it could be another

Answer (score 11):

As Jascha mentioned, `Vec<T>` implements `Deref<Target=[T]>` and `DerefMut`.

Note the specific syntax here: `Target` is an associated type of `Deref` (not an input) and the implementation looks like:

```
impl<T> Deref for Vec<T> {
    type Target = [T];

    // ..
}
```

The fact that `Target` is an associated type of `Deref` is important, because it means that `Deref` **can only ever be implemented once** for any given (concrete) type.

This, in turns, means that when resolving methods on a type, the compiler can easily apply *deref coercions*. That is, as long as no method of the given name is found, it can see if the current type can be deref'ed once more and try again (yes, this can be chained).

---

In the current situation this means the compiler:

- looks for a `sort_by_key` on `&mut Vec<T>`, there is none
- looks for a `sort_by_key` on `&mut [T]`, it exists

it then transforms the call from:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 3, 2];
v.sort_by_key(...);
```

into:

```
let mut v = vec![1, 3, 2];
(&mut *v).sort_by_key(...);
```

automatically.

Comment: thank you very much for your explanation now understand better how it works

Comment: I was thinking that maybe it would be good to put on the title "Why I can use sort_by_key with a Vec? ( Deref )" but did not know before, maybe if that word is added, makes it easier for others to access the information you and other detailed in this question. But I do not know if it would be good to add that to the title?

Comment: @AngelAngel: I don't know :x

Comment: @AngelAngel no, it would not be useful. Putting `Deref` in the title would require people to *know the answer* before they are even able to *ask the question*.

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks for answering, I thought the same, so I ask that. But if someone is looking for information about Defer, they somehow could access this information, but you are right in what you said, thanks for your time