# Why does applying & to a String return a &str?

Tags: string, rust, dereference

In this example code [from the Rust documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/string/struct.String.html):

```
fn takes_str(s: &str) { }

let s = String::from("Hello");

takes_str(&s);
```

What exactly is going on behind the scenes that causes `&s` to become a `&str` instead of a `&String`?  The documentation seems to suggest that there's some dereferencing going on, but I thought `*` was for dereferencing, not `&`?

Comment: See [`Deref` coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html). The second code sample is almost exactly what you have.

Comment: maybe this help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437375/why-i-can-use-sort-by-key-with-a-vec for Deref

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's going on here is called [deref coercions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/deref-coercions.html). These allow references to types that implement the [Deref trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html) to be used in place of references to other types. As your example shows, `&String` can be used anywhere a `&str` is required, because `String` implements `Deref` to `str`.